# What's the point in constraining the shape of a TensorFlow's placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

https://web.archive.org/web/20170218000039/https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_ios/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/resources/faq.md states that:

> The `tf.placeholder()` op allows you to define tensors that must be fed, and optionally allows you to constrain their shape as well.

What's the point in constraining the shape of a placeholder? Is it just for code clarity, or does it have other advantages such as reducing the running time?

Comment: FYI, theano doesn't have shape constraint for "placeholder" equivalent, only tensor rank. But devs seems to talk about adding better shape inference for more optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main advantage of constraining the shape of a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) is that the (possibly partial) shape can be used to infer the shapes of tensors that are derived from it. Shape inference can then be used to detect errors at the point where you create an op, rather than at runtime. The shape inference is analogous to type inference in a [gradually typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradual_typing) language, like TypeScript, where if you provide more information about the shapes (types) of placeholders (arguments), the system can use that information to improve the robustness of your program.

For example, if you had the following program:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = tf.matmul(x, y)

# ...

sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: [[1., 2., 3.]], y: [[2.], [3.]]})
```

...you would get a runtime error from the `MatMul` kernel.

By contrast, if you constrained the shapes in the `tf.placeholder()` calls as follows:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[2, 1])
z = tf.matmul(x, y)
```

...you'd get an error when you call `tf.matmul()`.

Shape inference can also improve the performance at runtime. There are various cases where the result of `tf.shape()` can be constant folded, and other optimizations will be made, which reduce the number of operations that must run. Backprop code in particular has to be very conservative about the shapes of its arguments, and additional static information there can result in much simpler graphs.

Comment: Can I have a feature request for TF - add symmetry options when specifying `placeholder`, since there are specialized BLAS routines dealing with symmetrical matrices.

Comment: That's something we're considering (via some kind of named symbolic dimension in `tf.TensorShape`), but it wouldn't hurt to post a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) with the feature request as well!